# Is $\lim_{k \to \infty} x_k^{\frac 1k} = r$ true?

Tags: limits

Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence. If $\lim_{k\to \infty}\frac {x_{k+1}}{x_k}=r$ holds, then is $\lim_{k \to \infty} x_k^{\frac 1k} = r$ true?

Thanks all your help.

Comment: Yes, it is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A general theorem is that if $a_n \rightarrow a$ then 
$$\sqrt[n]{a_1a_2\cdots a_n} \rightarrow a.$$
Apply this with $a_n=\frac{x_{n}}{x_{n-1}}$ to get the desired result.

Comment: This is nice. Note you're using Cesàro's theorem after taking logarithms. =)

Comment: Yes that is exactly the proof.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The more general claim is that if $(x_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ is a sequence of positive numbers,

$$\liminf_{n\to\infty} \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}\leqslant \liminf_{n\to\infty}  x_n^{1/n}\leqslant \limsup_{n\to\infty}  x_n^{1/n}\leqslant \limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$$

In fact, to extend of Rene's answer, we can use another theorem: if $(x_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ is any sequence, and we define $\widehat{x_n}=\dfrac 1 n\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n} x_n$ it generally olds that $$\liminf_{n\to\infty} x_n\leqslant \liminf_{n\to\infty}  \widehat{x_n} \leqslant \limsup_{n\to\infty}  \widehat{x_n}\leqslant \limsup_{n\to\infty}{x_n}$$

In particular, if the $x_n>0$ and we take $y_n=\log x_n$, we get that $x_n\to x $ implies $(x_1\ldots x_n)^{1/n}\to x$.

Comment: +1. I just love it when the OP asks, "Is it true?", and someone comments, "Yes, it is." without any remarks or whatsoever. So, my +1 was for the fact that you gave an explanation. :)

Comment: @Sanath: The commentor was busy typing the proof.

Comment: @SwapnilTri I did not mean it as an insult, forgive me if you were offended. I said that because I do the same, and think about how the OP would respond. I have a young mind, and so I think of quite funny reactions, leading to the above comment. Anyway, +1, SwapnilTri!

Comment: @Sanath: No, I wasn't offended. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is, indeed, true.

Suppose $\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{x_{k+1}}{x_k}=r$
Then, $|\frac{x_{k+1}}{x_k}-r|<\epsilon$ for all x>=M. i.e.

$r-\epsilon<\frac{x_{M+1}}{x_M}<r+\epsilon$

$r-\epsilon<\frac{x_{M+2}}{x_{M+1}}<r+\epsilon$

......
$r-\epsilon<\frac{x_{n}}{x_{n-1}}<r+\epsilon$

Multiply all the equations to get

${(r-\epsilon)}^{n-m}<\frac{x_n}{x_M}<{(r+\epsilon)}^{n-m}$

Take $n^th$ roots in the above equation

${(r-\epsilon)}^{1-{m/n}}<\frac{{x_n}^{1/n}}{{x_M}^{1/n}}<{(r+\epsilon)}^{1-{m/n}}$

Now you can easily prove your claim..