# Ratio test and root test limit.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

A professor once told that if limit of th ratio/root test is a finite L then the limit of the other test yields the same number L. Can someone confirm this? in which cases can I say that both tests yield the same limit? Thanks.

Comment: The root test is strictly stronger. We have (assuming everything nonzero) $$\liminf_{n\to\infty} \frac{\lvert a_{n+1}\rvert}{\lvert a_n\rvert} \leqslant \liminf_{n\to\infty} \lvert a_n\rvert^{1/n} \leqslant \limsup_{n\to\infty} \lvert a_n\rvert^{1/n} \leqslant \limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{\lvert a_{n+1}\rvert}{\lvert a_n\rvert},$$ so if the limit of the ratios exists, the limit of the roots also exists, and they are the same. But the limit of the roots can exist without the limit of the ratios existing.

Comment: See also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/700370/relationship-between-ratio-test-and-power-series-radius-of-convergence).

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/814500/is-lim-k-to-infty-x-k-frac-1k-r-true/814514#814514

Comment: An example of a series for which the Ratio test fails but the Root test does not is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1/(2^{n+(-1)^{n}})$

Comment: I thank you @DanielFischer. I only have one doubt left: if the limit of the ratios is infinite, is the limit of the roots infinite too?

Comment: Yes, the inequalities above hold also for infinite $\liminf$, so $\frac{\lvert a_{n+1}\rvert}{\lvert a_n\rvert}\to \infty \implies \lvert a_n\rvert^{1/n} \to \infty$.

Comment: Thank you again! It's all clear to me now.