# Does $\limsup_{n \to \infty }\left | \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}} \right |=\limsup_{n \to \infty }\left | a_n \right |^{1/{n}}$?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, power-series

Question: Does $\limsup_{n \to \infty }\left | \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}} \right |=\limsup_{n \to \infty }\left | a_n \right |^{1/{n}}$?

I guess the identity is true, given $\limsup_{n \to \infty }\left | \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}} \right |\neq 0$, and here is my "proof", is it correct?

Proof:

Suppose all $a_n$ are non-zero, and $s=\limsup_{n \to \infty }\left | \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}} \right | \neq 0$,

For any $\varepsilon >0$, there exists $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n>N$ implies:
$$s-\varepsilon < \underset{m\geq n}{\text{sup}}\left | \frac{a_{m+1}}{a_{m}} \right |<s+\varepsilon$$
$$\Rightarrow s-\varepsilon < \left | \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}} \right |<s+\varepsilon$$
for all $n>N$.
$$\Rightarrow (s-\varepsilon)|a_{n}| < |a_{n+1}|<(s+\varepsilon)|a_{n}|$$
$$\Rightarrow (s-\varepsilon)^{n-N}|a_{N+1}| < |a_{n+1}|<(s+\varepsilon)^{n-N}|a_{N+1}|$$
where we may set $0<\varepsilon <s$, where $s \neq0$. So, for all $n>N$, we have:
$$\Rightarrow (s-\varepsilon)^{1-\frac{N+1}{n+1}}|a_{N+1}|^{1/{n+1}} < |a_{n+1}|^{1/{n+1}}<(s+\varepsilon)^{1-\frac{N+1}{n+1}}|a_{N+1}|^{1/{n+1}}$$
So, for $n>N$:
$$ (s-\varepsilon)^{1-\frac{N+1}{n+1}}|a_{N+1}|^{1/{n+1}} \leq  \underset{m\geq n}{\text{sup}}|a_{m+1}|^{1/{m+1}}\leq (s+\varepsilon)^{1-\frac{N+1}{n+1}}|a_{N+1}|^{1/{n+1}}$$
Now,
$$(s+\varepsilon)^{1-\frac{N+1}{n+1}}|a_{N+1}|^{1/{n+1}}\underset{n \to \infty }{\rightarrow}(s+\varepsilon)(s+\varepsilon)^0(1)=s+\varepsilon$$
and
$$(s-\varepsilon)^{1-\frac{N+1}{n+1}}|a_{N+1}|^{1/{n+1}}\underset{n \to \infty }{\rightarrow}(s-\varepsilon)(s-\varepsilon)^0(1)=s-\varepsilon$$

By comparison test,
$$s-\varepsilon \leq \limsup_{n \to \infty }\left | a_n \right |^{1/{n}} \leq s+\varepsilon $$
for arbitrarily small $\varepsilon$.

So, $$s=\limsup_{n \to \infty }\left | a_n \right |^{1/{n}}$$ and we are done.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: In general they’re not equal. But an inequality holds between them. See the chapter on series in Rudin’s mathematical analysis book

Comment: See this classic [example](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2395131/1085900).

Comment: If $a_{2n}=\frac1{n!}$ and $a_{2n+1}=1,$ the ratio $\limsup$ is $+\infty,$ but $\limsup \sqrt[n]{a_n}=1.$

Comment: The first sentence of your "proof" should give you a hint: "Suppose all $a_n$ are non-zero". What if they're not? Just consider the sequence $0,1,0,1,0,1,\cdots$. Then one limit is not defined and the other is obviously $1$.

Comment: Your removal of the $\sup$ is not allowed. If $\sup b_m>z,$ it is not true that all $b_m>z.$

Comment: Not correct, see above comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two lim sups are not equal. The flaw in your proof is that the assertion
$$s-\varepsilon < \underset{m\geq n}{\text{sup}}\left | \frac{a_{m+1}}{a_{m}} \right |<s+\varepsilon \qquad\forall n>N$$
does not imply
$$ s-\varepsilon < \left | \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}} \right |<s+\varepsilon
\qquad\forall n>N.$$
A counterexample is
$$a_n=\begin{cases} 1&\text{$n$ odd}\\2&\text{$n$ even}\end{cases}.$$ With this sequence, $\sup_{m\ge n}|a_{m+1}/a_m|=2$ while the ratio $|a_{n+1}/a_n|$ oscillates between $\frac12$ and $2$. (And  $\limsup |a_{n+1}/a_n|=2$ while $\limsup |a_n|^{1/n}=1$.)

Comment: If I replace the flaw by:

Suppose $a_n \neq 0$, and $s=\lim\left | \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right | \neq 0$. For any $\varepsilon >0$, there exists $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n>N$ $\Rightarrow s-\varepsilon < \left | \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}} \right |<s+\varepsilon \Rightarrow$ for all $n>N$, $s-\varepsilon \leq  \underset{m\geq n}{\text{sup}}\left | \frac{a_{m+1}}{a_{m}} \right |\leq s+\varepsilon$.

Then the original article can be corrected into a proof of the new statement $\lim \left | \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right |=\limsup \left | {a_n} \right |^{1/n}$, right?

Comment: But the new statement $\lim |a_{n+1}/a_n|=\limsup |a_n|^{1/n}$ is not true; the counterexample shows that the LHS limit need not exist.

Comment: But what if $\lim|a_{n+1}/a_n|$ does exist? Then the statement would be true right? If this limit exists, then the radius of convergence of the power series $\sum a_nx^n$ has the radius of convergence $1/\lim|a_{n+1}/a_n|$, which should be consistent with the Cauchy-Hadamard formula.

Comment: Do you mean only the following is true: If $\lim|a_{n+1}/a_n|$ exists, then it must be equal to $\limsup|a_n|^{1/n}$.

Comment: Yes. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/814500/215011 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/69386/215011